# Hour & minutes overwritten by year using touch command

Tags: shell

The shell command `touch -t 2203231037 file` stores the year in the `HH:MM` file attribute resulting in `2022` instead of `10:37`. This is a curriculum exercise, with the remark that this side effect won't be consider as wrong for the purpose of the exercise.

However, what is the correct usage of the touch command to get the right time posted for hours and minutes?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Linux shell usage questions should be posted to [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su] instead.

Comment: touch -t 202201011037 file

Comment: This has nothing to do with your shell. `touch` is a separate program, and will interpret its own arguments the same no matter which shell you use to run `touch`.

Comment: The argument you are giving should be interpreted as 10:37 AM  on 2022-03-23. Files have modification, creation, and access timestamps (which ones depends on your file system), and each one is a single combined date/time stamp.